# How do you create an automation API POST test request using Resty

Tags: api, go, automated-tests

I have managed to successfully setup my API automation tests in Go using Resty and execute a GET request.

I am however struggling to get a POST API test to return a 200 instead I receive a 400 error message. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Please see my code below. (The POST request works in Postman by the way!)

```
func Test_Post(t *testing.T){
    client := resty.New()
    resp, _ := client.R().
    SetBody(`{
            "text": "Hello, I am learning how to test APIs with Postman!"  
    }`).
    Post("https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/yoda")

    assert.Equal(t, 200, resp.StatusCode())
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a Content-Type. This should work:

```golang
func Test_Post(t *testing.T){
    client := resty.New()
    resp, _ := client.R().
    SetBody(`{
            "text": "Hello, I am learning how to test APIs with Postman!"  
    }`).
    SetHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").
    Post("https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/yoda")

    assert.Equal(t, 200, resp.StatusCode())

}
```

If you pass the client a json-serializable data type instead of a string, it will know that you intend to send JSON, and set the header correctly:

```golang
resp, _ := client.R().
    SetBody(map[string]string{
        "text": "Hello, I am learning how to test APIs with Postman!",
    }).
    Post("https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/yoda")
```

Comment: Thanks very much it does work now appreciate the quick response